# How to really convert xml to json with native dll (giving up)

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am looking for a code example for `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter` to convert XML to JSON without having to install external dll's. But all examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258762/serialize-in-a-human-readable-text-format) utilize `DataContractJsonSerializer` and convert XML like this:

```
<temp>42</temp>
```

to produce JSON like:

```
"\"<temp>42<\\/temp>\""
```

instead of, what I am really looking for:

```
{"temp":42}
```

Apparently, both outputs are JSON, but how do I obtain the latter kind?

By the way, my input is an XElement, not XmlElement.

I already found code to convert JSON to XML using the opposite method `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader`, which works kind of nice, and does NOT utilize `DataContractJsonDeserializer` or something like that. So I guess I need to find sample code for `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter` without `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Unfortunately, the MSDN pages like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908361(v=vs.110).aspx) on CreateJsonWriter do not show code samples.

---

Update:

I am giving up on this question. Apparently, I should need to switch to the NewtonSoft dll.

The purpose of my question was to quickly create a conversion to translate a sample xml data file, and it is always nice to have a new tool in my personal Lib. Now I will just use an online conversion tool for this one xml.

Thanks all of you for pointing out that I really need to get the Newtonsoft dll if I want to do further JSON stuff.

---

Comments:

- similar to possible duplicate questions: very likely that others tried something like I did, because it sounds attractive, but there is no conclusive answer that it is just not possible
- other seemingly duplicate questions almost always focus on the Newtonsoft dll, while my question is on the native dll's.

---

Duplicate:

Looks so, but I point out that the output is some wrong kind of correct JSON, and ask for a way of calling that method to get 'useful' JSON.

The commenters point out details about why this happens, namely the native dll has limitations.

Comment: That is about using a downloaded dll from NewtonSoft, probably very useful, but I would like to try the native dll first. Also has an example using Serialization, what gives me the wrong kind of json as mentioned.

Comment: It is not only about JSON.NET. The accepted answer contains JSON.NET solution (since it is the most simple), but there are other answers. For example, this one uses .NET Framework native classes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32412316/3218692

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I am trying this out. Just need to find the reference for System.Web.Script . . .

Comment: I tried using `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter()` to convert XML to JSON a while back and it didn't really work, because it had all sorts of restrictions on the XML, including having a specific root element name, no namespaces, and special attributes to indicate whether elements map to JSON objects or arrays.

Comment: Most useful doc page is probably [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924435.aspx).

Comment: @dbc I guess that this makes `JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter` useless for me. Thanks for pointing out details.

Comment: @dbc If your comment were an "Answer", I'd accepted it, because it points out 'why' CreateJsonWriter is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `using Newtonsoft.Json;` anyway.
I guess it's one of the most popular `.net` library for working with `json`.

And you can install it by [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814027/364429)

```
// To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

// To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Some guide you can find [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm). 
Also this [article](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm) might be useful

For `XDocument` please see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037194/364429)

Comment: This needs `using Newtonsoft.Json;`, right?

Comment: @Roland definitely

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Xml document to JSON using json.net

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm

Comment: Do you mean it is not possible with JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter from the native dll?

Comment: Nope...JSON.Net will makes our life easy...     JsonReaderWriterFactory require extra work..  that's it

Comment: Preferences, OK, but if I just got  JsonReaderWriterFactory  to work that would be nice. However, if the microsoft does not work or is lacking essential documentation, I will definitely go for JSON.Net

Comment: If JSON.Net is not an option for you then check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157441/is-it-possible-to-use-jsonreaderwriterfactory-to-convert-xml-to-json-without-usi      this leads you to this artile http://www.phdcc.com/xml2json.htm  They don't use JSONReaderWriterFactory but does not use any external library

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I tried that approach and got the wrong kind of json output, as mentioned